# Mass renaming of records

Tags: account

I'm currently doing some volunteer work for a non profit and one of the things they wanted was a way to mass rename existing account records. Is there a quick way to do this that I'm missing? I looked into process builder and workflow rules, but those only can execute on an edit.

Comment: Have you tried checking inline editing in lightning https://salesforceoke.blogspot.com/2019/09/salesforce-lightning-list-view-inline.html#:~:text=Inline%20edit%20row%20level%20actions,once%20with%20mass%20inline%20editing ,if you are using classic try checking mass update.http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-articles/bulk-update-records-in-salesforce.html#:~:text=Go%20to%3A%20Setup%3E%20App%20Setup,t%20forget%20to%20click%20Save

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of records, I've done mass record changes via dataloader.io.  I would export the accounts out to a csv/excel file, modify them then mass import them back using the account ID to link the import/export.

If you're doing this with less than 10k records you can actually get a free version of DataLoader, otherwise just pay for one month an cancel.

Comment: When I import them back does it update the record? If so could I just have a process that runs whenever there is an edit and that would take care of the renaming?

Comment: @Aroon yes it updates the record.  But as far as a process to auto-update the names, why would you need to run a separate process after importing them with new names?  Perhaps you should get a bit more specific in your question.

Comment: I would be using the process anyway to change the names of new records being brought in from a source I can't readily change the exporting behavior. It's a service to manage donations and I won't have any access to it. My thought was, if I have the process in place already, I could just import all the records back and the process would handle the renaming.